# spring mvc multiple array values append inslide [[]] using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, spring-mvc, multidimensional-array

I'm working spring mvc with mongoDb

I got multiple image name values from the collection:

```
Ex: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg....
```

Question:

Now I want this values to inside the [[]]

```
Ex : [["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]]
```

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var slices = [];
 <c:forEach var="items" items="${LiteCOLL.dwi}" varStatus="status">
    <c:forEach items="${items.TTP}" var="item">
        slices.push("${item}");     
    </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>  

    var params = [];
    var data = [["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]];
    params["images"] = data;

</script>
```

I found some solutions but I can't able to resolve it

Comment: are you getting the data from db and want to push in to array using javascript ?

Comment: yes ... I want to do same

Comment: is this your response from db `1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg` ?

Comment: @SangramBadi yes

Comment: please check the aswer

Comment: @SangramBadi yeah ok

Comment: @SangramBadi Yes I got the solution with below two answers but York chen made very little change with my code and it's working fine. Your answer also working fine and now i don't know which one i should  fix answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you already get an array, what you need is an array of array, so what you need to do is just create a new array and push the "slices" in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var slices = [];
 <c:forEach var="items" items="${LiteCOLL.dwi}" varStatus="status">
    <c:forEach items="${items.TTP}" var="item">
        slices.push("${item}");     
    </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>  

  var result = [slices];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadFun(){
    var dbData = '1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg';
    var splitStr = dbData.split(',');

    var firstArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<splitStr.length; i++) {
        firstArray.push(splitStr[i]);
    }


    var secondArray = [];
    secondArray.push(firstArray);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(secondArray));
}
```

1st need to split then
You need to declear two array and need to push one by one